# Real world examples of a kind of "sorted" data

Tags: terminology, representation

Consider a sorted list of numbers which is "cut," so that it is increasing except for one jump. For instance the order might be,

> 11, 12, 13, 14, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

What kinds of data naturally have this representation, with one or possibly many "cuts" obscuring the default ordering? The only one I can think of is a deck of cards, but I was asked to produce examples of data that might look like this in an interview. Weeks later, and I still can't think of any, but my curiosity prevails.

Is there a special name for this kind of data? I tried googling "cut data" but that obviously didn't work.

All insight is appreciated.

[Edit] From the discussions below this appears to have some interesting relationships with symmetry groups, and what sorts of rearrangements are possible with just the cut operation. I may have to ask my local mathematicians what I can do with this.

Comment: Hour of the day?  Day of the month?  Position in degrees of a point on a spinning top?

Comment: I don't mean data that cycles, I mean data that is ordered, and then cut. Something like a list of days of the months in a calendar year is ordered by what month it is, and while you could probably manipulate it with sufficiently many cuts to get it back to a sorted list of integers, that certainly is not a helpful representation of that data. Think of a new deck of cards which is cut four times. It is initially sorted, and then that sorting is distorted, and handed off to someone else to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick analysis, it's obvious to see that any sequence of "cuts" results in a single cut with respect to a different index. In fact, it is only the most recent cut point that matters, as that value will end up at the front of the list, and it will be equivalent to a cut of this data from the original index of that element.

So not so interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few off the top of my head.

The first is the hour of the day as it rolls into a new day: `... 22 23 0 1 2 ...`.

The second is the alpha ordering on file names: `pax1 pax10 pax11 ... pax19 pax2 pax20 ...`.

Yet another is the months of the financial year (in Australia, most companies close off their financial year at the end of June): `7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5 6`.

Comment: The second two are good. I think file names, if it is actually cut data, would be a perfect example! I'll have to look into it more to determine whether every naturally sorted file list can be cut into the pattern you metnion, because it's not at all obvious to me that this is the case.

Comment: @Bean, there'll only be one cut if there's one transition (eg, `pax2` thru `pax11` giving `10 11 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`) so it's only suitable for certain file combinations. The months is probably a better bet since it's guaranteed to be limited to those number for a given financial year.

Comment: I don't believe that filenames work as cut data. Consider the following list of strings ["pax1", "pax10", "pax2"] can never be cut in a way that gives ["pax1", "pax2", "pax10"]...

Comment: Yes, I think we arrived at the same conclusion at the same time. Still, small lists of data don't require any special handling, so for instance, while I might optimize a binary search for cut data, it is a waste of time to do so for a list of months or hours...

Comment: @Bean, see my previous comment. It will work for limited strings, not for all of them. The data that naturally has this property are the numbers 2 thru 11 (or 2 thru any teen up to 19), sorted alphabetically. The limited possibilities there are why I suggested months in the calendar year would be better.